# How to delay the drawing of elements in p5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have an array of words and I want to display the following element in my array only after a certain amount of seconds have passed. When I iterate over every element draw effectively displays every element but it does so at the same time. How can I delay this process?

Here's how the code looks like at the moment:

```
let canvas;
let img;
let x = 0;
let speed = 3;
let words = ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvas.parent('canvas-holder');
  canvas.style('z-index', '-1');
  canvas.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background('#fcfcfc');
  words.forEach(word => {
    text(word, x, 200);
    fill(0, 102, 153);
    textSize(32);
  });
  x += speed;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you can do a timeout in setup and set a boolean on completion then only display if the boolean is true

Answer (score 0):

To add a delay between words so that all words are not displayed at the same time you can access the array by index and increment the index based on frame count.

```js
let x = 0;
let speed = 3;
let words = ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test'];
let wordIndex = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 100);
  frameRate(10);
  fill(0, 102, 153);
  textSize(32);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  // increment the word index every tenth frame
  if (frameCount % 10 === 0){
    wordIndex++;
  }
  // when we reach the end of the array reset x and wordIndex
  if (wordIndex === words.length){
    wordIndex = 0;
    x = 0;
  }
  var word = words[wordIndex];
    text(word, x, height/2);
    x += speed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```